# Calculate minimum area rectangle for a polygon

Tags: c++, c, geometry, java

I have a need to calculate the minimum area rectangle (**smallest possible rectangle**) around the polygon.

The only input i have is the number of points in polygon.

I have the co-ordinates of the points also.

Comment: Only number of points ? or do you have the co-ordinates also?

Comment: Is the polygon at an arbitrary orientation or does the rectangle have to be orthogonal to the coordinate system?

Comment: you need to have coordinates.  or, have the length of a side and a restriction that all the sides have the same length.

or you could answer : 4.      (number of points in rectangle)

hehe.

Comment: Yes polygon could be in arbitrary orientation and for rectangle only think it should be the samllest possible in terms of area

Comment: Did you even try to do this yourself?

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479435/fit-rectangle-around-points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [rotating calipers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) algorithm for a convex polygon, or the convex hull otherwise.  You will of course need the coordinates of the points in the polygon, not just the number of points.

Comment: I think it will help me .. more precisely i  have to calculate the width and length of polygon !!!

Comment: that's not problem: as you apply the algorithm, you calculate the width and length of a bounding box aligned to each edge in turn.

Answer (score 9):

This is called [Minimum Bounding Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms), it's most basic algorithm used in OCR packages. You can find an implementation using Rotating Calipers from the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) package. Once you get the source code, check out this file,

```
cv/src/cvrotcalipers.cpp
```

The method you need is `cvMinAreaRect2()`.

Comment: I am unable to find the this method .
Can u give me the precise for this
thanks

Comment: It's here http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#WMkTvnMDpLM/cv/src/cvrotcalipers.cpp&q=cvMinAreaRect2

Answer (score 1):

First do a [grahm-scan](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos226/demo/ah/GrahamScan.html) and get the [convex hull](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos226/demo/ah/ConvexHull.html) of the set of points.  Then you can use something like [minimum rectangle discussed here](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0107/algorithm_0107.htm#Minimal%20Rectangle)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following algorithm

1. Rotate the  polygon onto the XY plane
2. Pick 1 edge and align this edge with the X axis(use arctan). Use the min/max x,y to find the bounding rectangle. Compute Area and store in list
3. Do the same for remaining edges in clipped polygon.
4. Pick the rectangle with the minimum Area.
5. Rotate Bounding Rectangle back for Coplanar reverse rotation of Step 1 and step 2

for more detail check link [Minimum-Area-Rectangle](http://learnfromtask.blogspot.in/2016/12/how-to-find-minimum-area-bounding.html)

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, you'll need the coordinates of the points to get the answer. If the rectangle is aligned to the X and Y aces, then the solution is trivial. If you want the smallest possible rectangle, at any angle, then you'll need to do some sort of optimization process.

Comment: thanks mark for ur comment
Yes i need the rectanle at any angle.
Could you plz elaborate optimization process

Comment: Several people have already mentioned the rotating calipers algorithm. That's basically how it's done. You do the equivalent of the basic min/max bounding box, but with the coordinate system rotated to the angle of each of the sides.