# Minimum bounding rectangle of a circle on a sphere

Tags: r, geometry, great-circle

What R packages are available to calculate the minimum bounding box for a great circle?

For example:

```
box <- polycirc( c( longitude, latitude ), distance=35 )
```

This would return the bounding box for the circle with a radius of 35 kilometres from the central point at the given coordinates (on Earth). Where:

```
box.longitude_min = The longitude of the circle's western-most point.
box.longitude_max = The longitude of the circle's eastern-most point.
box.latitude_min = The latitude of the circle's southern-most point.
box.latitude_max = The latitude of the circle's northern-most point.
```

Something like this should already exist in R, but I cannot find it. The closest I've found (from SO), which I am currently transmogrifying to R, is:

http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

Also, what is the word (if any) for *minimum bounding rectangle of a circle*? (The opposite of [circumscribed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle).)

Comment: There is also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303265/algorithm-for-determining-minimum-bounding-rectangle-for-collection-of-lat-lon-co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given to me:

```
  library( geosphere )
  p <- c( longitude, latitude )
  box <- apply( destPoint( p, c(0, 90, 180, 270), distance ), 2, range )
  print( box )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `polycirc` function to generate the points of the circle and then `min` and `max` to found the bounding box :)

```
require(pgirmess)
circle <- polycirc(20, c(10, 20))
plot(circle, type = "l")
rect(min(circle[,1]), min(circle[,2]), max(circle[,1]), max(circle[,2]))
```

Comment: Will this work for a circle on the surface of a sphere? (Crossing the poles or 180th Meridian?) And how would you use latitude and longitude?

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: Oooops.... I did not read your question correctly (sorry, was early in the morning). No, this would need some tweaking then.