# centralized latitude and longitude from set

Tags: google-maps

I have few values of latitude and longitude.

How can i found centralized latitude and longitude from them? and How can i find out proper zoom parameter?

Comment: are you trying to center the map and plotting the markers with the lat and lng values?  or are you simply wish to find only the center point?

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse your question - use the technique from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303265) to find the bounding rectangle, then take the average of the corners to find the central point.  The distance across the rectangle defines the required zoom.