# Fit rectangle around points

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to fit a rectangle around a set of 8 2D-Points, while trying to **minimize the covered area**.

Example:

[image]

The rectangle may be scaled and rotated. However it needs to stay a rectangle.

My first approach was to brute force each possible rotation, fit the rectangle as close as possible, and calculate the covered area. The best fit would be then the rotation with the lowest area.

However this does not really sound like the best solution.

Is there any better way for doing this?

Comment: So, what's the complexity of your brute force solution? There are O(n) edges on the convex hull. Even if you use a brute force rectangle shrink wrap, you end up O(n^2), with th(n^1.5) in practice.

Comment: I was hoping to find a better solution, instead of a brute force approach

Comment: Why don't you like O(n^2)?

Comment: I'm doing this in an realtime environment, and I am trying to get it as fast as possible, since every nanosecond counts

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to cache the convex hull between frames?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: I'm not sure is any edges of he convex hull is part of an edge of the minimizing rectangle. So how do you expect to get away with O(n^2)?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak the edges change every frame, and I'm doing this for many edges

Comment: @MrSmith42 - My gut tells me the converse; that one edge of the convex hull *will* be part of the minimal rectangle.  Can't prove it yet, though...

Comment: @MrSmith42 if no edge of the convex hull coincides with the bounding box, either of the rotations until it does should provide a lower area. Even if that isn't so, you get area as a trigonometric function of the rotation angle given by four extreme points, and you still end up with O((convex hull size)^2). Even faster, actually, since you can find the extremes in O(log n) once you know the hull.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: The example looks like that this is not the case.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I'd try aligning the bounding box with the top two points.

Comment: So... compute the convex hull; for each range of angles between the convex hull directions mod 90 degrees, the rectangle is bounded by the same four points. Find the minimum of the corresponding area function (whose form is known in advance). Take the lowest minimum.

Comment: @JanDvorak any proof that this will lead to the best solution, and does not miss any possible angle?

Comment: @tobspr you did check each angle, one range out of the full quarter-circle at a time, didn't you?

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah. I could compare it with the brute force implementation. I'd prefer some explanation why this leads to the best solution, if possible, though.

Comment: @tobspr as in, why it doesn't skip any smaller box, or why there isn't any faster algorithm? The former is quite clear. The latter I'm not sure about. Hint for the former: The function is a product of two offset sines. The function has a single minimum over its period of ninety degrees, and finding its two extrema should be very easy because of symmetry. You don't even need the derivative.

Comment: @JanDvorak feel free to add an answer so I can accept it

Comment: First you'd have to tell me how your approach differs from mine (unless you meant to restrict the angle to a multiple of some fixed value and check every possibility separately, which would be really slow and would only approximate the correct result).

Comment: This once was asked for under the `java` tag (one could nearly consider this as a "duplicate"...). I created a compilable, standalone example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23956275/3182664 , and the logic is mainly summarized in the `MinOrientedBoundingBoxComputer` class. It should not be sooo difficult to port this to C++. You could probably use `glm` and its `vec2` classes to emulate a `Point2D`, and a `mat3` to emulate an `AffineTransform`.

Comment: @Marco13 I consider this an `[algorithm]` question, not a `[c++]` question. Too bad there's no explanation in your code. Maybe close in the other direction?

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, the other question is not really "good", as it mainly asks for code, but I'm not sure whether this justifies closing (and eventaully deleting) it. Some details about the approach are nicely described in [the answer that I linked to from mine](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/), and my code is "only" a quick implementation of this approach. I wanted implement this anyhow, and in the meantime, created a revised version of it at https://github.com/javagl/Geom/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/geom/OrientedBoundingBoxes.java , with some (although few) comments.

Comment: Oh boy you found a use for calculus in trivial programming!

Comment: @Supuhstar calculus only needed if you don't trust the intuition of two or three people and a proof that came thirty minutes too late ;-) (and "trivial programming" is a bit of a stretch, too)

Comment: @JanDvorak  by "trivial", I mean as opposed to analyzing stock market trends or live-calculating a rocket's trajectory :P

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "try every possible rotation", as there are infinitely many of them, but this basic idea actually yields a very efficient solution:

The first step is to compute the convex hull. How much this actually saves depends on the distribution of your data, but [for points picked uniformly from a unit disk, the number of points on the hull is expected to be O(n^1/3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346090/what-is-the-expected-size-of-the-convex-hull-of-n-points-selected-randomly-in). There are a [number of ways to do that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms):

- If the points are already sorted by one of their coordinates, the Graham scan algorithm does that in O(n). For every point in the given order, connect it to the previous two in the hull and then remove every concave point (the only candidate are those neighboring the new point) on the new hull.
- If the points are not sorted, the gift-wrapping algorithm is a simple algorithm that runs at O(n*h). For each point on the hull starting from the leftmost point of the input, check every point to see if it's the next point on the hull. `h` is the number of points on the hull.
- [Chen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan%27s_algorithm) promises O(n log h) performance, but I haven't quite explored how it works.
- <sub>another simle idea would be to sort the points by their azimuth and then remove the concave ones. However, this only seems like O(n+sort) at first, but I'm afraid it actually isn't.</sub>

At this point, checking every angle collected thus far should suffice (as conjenctured by both me and Oliver Charlesworth, and for which Evgeny Kluev [offered a gist of a proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479435/fit-rectangle-around-points?noredirect=1#comment56701564_34479435)). Finally, let me refer to the relevant reference in [Lior Kogan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34480264/499214).

For each direction, the bounding box is defined by the same four (not necessarily distinct) points for every angle in that interval. For the candidate directions, you will have at least one arbitrary choice to make. Finding these points might seem like an O(h^2) task until you realise that the extremes for the axis-aligned bounding box are the same extremes that you start the merge from, and that consecutive intervals have their extreme points either identical or consecutive. Let us call the extreme points `A,B,C,D` in the clockwise order, and let the corresponding lines delimiting the bounding box be `a,b,c,d`.
[image]
So, let's do the math. The bounding box area is given by `|a,c| * |b,d|`. But `|a,c|` is just the vector `(AC)` projected onto the rectangle's direction. Let `u` be a vector parallel to `a` and `c` and let `v` be the perpendicular vector. Let them vary smoothly across the range. In the vector parlance, the area becomes `((AC).v) / |v| * ((BD).u) / |u|` = `{((AC).v) ((BD).u)} / {|u| |v|}`. Let us also choose that `u = (1,y)`. Then `v = (y, -1)`. If `u` is vertical, this poses a slight problem involving limits and infinities, so let's just choose `u` to be horizontal in that case instead. For numerical stability, let's just rotate 90° every `u` that is outside `(1,-1)..(1,1)`. Translating the area to the cartesian form, if desired, is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 32):

It has been shown that the minimum area rectangle of a set of points is collinear with one of the edges of the collection's convex hull polygon [["Determining the Minimum-Area Encasing Rectangle for an Arbitrary Closed Curve"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=360919) [Freeman, Shapira 1975]

An O(nlogn) solution for this problem was published in ["On the computation of minimum encasing rectangles and set diameters"](http://eprints.cs.vt.edu/archive/00000869/01/CS81017-R.pdf) [Allison, Noga, 1981]

A simple and elegant O(n) solution was published in ["A Linear time algorithm for the minimum area rectangle enclosing a convex polygon"](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1381&context=cstech) [Arnon, Gieselmann 1983] when the input is the convex hull (The complexity of [constructing a convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) is equal to the complexity of sorting the input points). The solution is based on the [Rotating calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) method described in [Shamos, 1978](http://euro.ecom.cmu.edu/people/faculty/mshamos/1978ShamosThesis.pdf). An online demonstration is available [here](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/march12014/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

They first thing that came to mind when I saw this problem was to use principal component analysis. I conjecture that the smallest rectangle is the one that satisfies two conditions: that the edges are parallel with the principal axes and that at least four points lie on the edges (bounded points). There should be an extension to n dimensions.

Comment: Huh? Edges parallel with the principal axes?  Then why is the fitted rectangle tilted?  Is my monitor crooked?

Comment: The principal axes are not parallel to the edges of your monitor. They are determined by the points.

Comment: Ah, so you define the direction of the edges ... not at all. :P

Comment: See Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics, Section 8.1.1 (pp212 onwards)